# Can the degree of a function take any value between $2$ and $2^n?$

Tags: combinatorics, functions, contest-math

> For each $n\in\mathbb{N},$ define $[n]:=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}.$ For a function $f:[n]\to[n],$ we say $D\subseteq[n]$ is invariant under $f$ if $f(D)\subseteq D.$ Let $\deg(f)$ be the number of invariant subsets under $f.$ Can $\deg(f)$ be any natural number between $2$ and $2^n?$ If not, what values are not possible? Note that the degree must be atleast $2$ since $\emptyset$ and $[n]$ are invariant under any function.

For each $k\in[n],$ there exists a function $f:[n]\to[n]$ with $\deg(f)=2^k.$ Just map each element in $[k-1]$ to itself. Now, if $x\in[n-1]\setminus[k-1],$ let $f(x)=x+1.$ Let $f(n)=k.$ Some counting shows that this function will have $2^{k-1}+2^{k-1}=2^k$ subsets that are invariant under it.

We can also achieve $2^{n-1}+1.$ Just map each element to $1.$ Then, any subset of $[n]$ containing $1$ will be invariant under it. There are $2^{n-1}$ of these. We also have to add $1$ to account for $\emptyset.$ Any other subset will not be invariant under this function. Hence, this function will have degree $2^{n-1}+1.$

We can also achieve $2^{k-1} + 2^{n-1}$ for each $k\in[n].$ Map everything in $[k]$ to itself. Map the rest to $k.$ This function will have $2^k+[(2^{n-k}-1)(2^{k-1})]=2^{k-1} + 2^{n-1}$ subsets that are invariant under it.

Heuristically speaking, it seems to me that we should be able to cover all values between $2$ and $2^n.$ There are a total of $n^n$ functions on $[n]$ and only $2^n-1$ values for the degree to be. It seems to me that there's a lot of freedom in how we can modify a function to change it's degree.

I was also thinking of writing the numbers as sums of distinct powers of $2.$ As in, if we write $13=2^3+2^2+2^0,$ maybe that will give us some insight on how to construct a function with degree $13.$ I haven't thought much about this idea yet, though.

An interesting property is that if $f:[n]\to[n]$ is a bijection, then $\deg(f)$ is a power of $2.$ In fact, $\deg(f)=2^m,$ where $m$ is the number of cycles that $f$ is a product of. This is because any invariant subset must be formed by picking some of these $m$ cycles. There are obviously ${m\choose0}+{m\choose1}+\ldots+{m\choose m}=2^m$ ways to do this. We may ask another question at this stage. Let the degree of $f$ be a power of $2.$ Must $f$ be a bijection? Since for $[n]$ being a bijection is equivalent to being one-one which is in turn equivalent to being onto, we may be able to answer this easily.

How do we proceed?

Comment: @CalvinLin Degree 3 is possible if $A \cup \{b\}$ is the entire domain. Consider $n = 3$ and $1,3 \mapsto 2; 2 \mapsto 1$.

Comment: For the question about "Let the degree of f be a power of 2. Must f be a bijection? ", the answer is no. Let $ A = [n-2]$. Let $f(a) = a+1$ for $ a\in [n-3]$, $f(n-2) = 1$, $f(n-1) = 1$, $f(n) = n-1$. Then, the invariant sets are exactly $\emptyset, [n-2], [n-1], [n]$.

Comment: @Tzimmo Ah yes, I just realized that as I was writing up my previous comment. Deleted it sadly.

Comment: @CalvinLin I also think the term "degree" is fine. There is a lot of concepts in math that are called degree. Some of them are connected to the degree of a polynomial, but often that connection is very vague or even non-existent.

Comment: @CalvinLin, actually this is inspired by a question from a math contest where we were asked to show that there exists $f$ for which $\deg(f)=2^k.$ In that question they used the term "degree" and I thought that that was the standard term for this concept.

Comment: $2^n -1$ is not possible, for $ n \geq 3$. Suppose not. Let $A$ be the subset that isn't invariant. Take $ B = [n] - A$. There is some $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b \in B$. Any proper subset of $ A$ containing $a$ is also non-invariant, but there are no other non-invariant subsets, so $|A| = 1$. Then, take $ c \neq f(a)$ (which exists as $n \geq 3$, then $ \{ a, c \}$ isn't invariant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check all functions for $n = 3$ for their degree. It's not too much work since there are just 27 of them. When considering that a lot of them can be transformed into each other by reordering the numbers $1$, $2$, and $3$, it becomes even less (only seven cases, I think).

You will notice that the degree $7$ does not occur, while all other numbers between $2$ and $8$ do.

UPDATE: I found a way to describe the numbers occurring as the degree of a map on an $n$-element set. Some arguments are still a bit vague, but I might improve on this later if you wish so.

Let $D_n$ be the set of all degrees $\deg f$ of functions $f \colon X \to X$, where $\#X = n$.

**Lemma.** $D_n \subseteq D_{n+1}$ for $n \geq 1$.

*Proof.* Let $d \in D_n$, so there exits $f \colon X \to X$ of degree $d$, where $X$ has $n$ elements. Choose $x \in X$. The sequence $(f^k(x))_{0 \leq k \leq n}$ needs to have repeating elements. Choose $k, l$ minimal such that $k < l$ and $f^k(x) = f^l(x)$. Define $y = f^k(x)$.

Let $*$ be an element not contained in $X$. Define a map $f_* \colon X_* \to X_*$, where $X_* = X \cup \{*\}$ via $y \mapsto *$, $* \mapsto f(y)$, and $z \mapsto f(z)$ for $z \neq y,*$. Claim: $\deg f = \deg f_*$.

If $Y_*$ is an $f_*$-stable subset of $X_*$, then $Y_* \cap X$ is an $f$-stable subset of $X$. If $Y$ is an $f$-stable subset of $X$, then exactly one of $Y$ and $Y \cup \{*\}$ is an $f_*$-stable subset of $X_*$. Concretely, $Y$ is stable iff $y \notin Y$ and $Y \cup \{*\}$ is stable iff $y \in Y$. This gives a bijection between stable subsets of $X$ and $X_*$, so $\deg f = \deg f_* \in D_{n+1}$. $\square$

Thus, it suffices to find the smallest $n$ such that $d \in D_n$ for a given $n$. Define the *stable subset depth* $\delta(n)$ of $n \in \mathbb{N}^+$ recursively as follows:
$$
\delta(1) = 0,\qquad \delta(n) = \min\left(\{\delta(n-1) + 1\} \cup \{\delta(a) + \delta(b) : 1 < a,b < n, n = ab\}\right) \text{ for } n > 1.
$$
This function can be calculated somewhat quickly as long as you are dealing with small numbers only. For larger numbers, calculation will probably take a while.

**Proposition.** $D_0$ = {1} and $D_n = \{d > 1 : \delta(d) \leq n\}$ for $n > 0$.

For the proof we need a little lemma. A *cycle* is a minimal non-empty stable subset. The *length* of a cycle is its number of elements. Note that a cycle of length $1$ is just a fixed point.

**Lemma.** Let $d > 0$. If $n$ is minimal such that $d \in D_n$, then for each $f \colon X \to X$ of degree $d$ with $\#X = n$, all cycles in $X$ are fixed points.

*Proof.* Let $C \subseteq X$ be a cycle of length $k$. Let $x \in X$. If $k > 1$, consider the set $X \setminus \{x\}$ with the map sending $y$ to $f(y)$ if $f(y) \neq x$ and to $f(x)$ otherwise. With a similar proof to the lemma above one sees that stable subsets of $X\setminus \{x\}$ under this map are in bijection with $f$-stable subsets of $X$. This is a contradiction since $X \setminus \{x\}$ has less than $n$ elements. Thus, $k = 1$ and $x$ is a fixed point. $\square$

*Proof of the proposition.* For $n = 0$ there is only the trivial map $f \colon \emptyset \to \emptyset$. The only subset $\emptyset \subset \emptyset$ is stable, so $\deg f = 0$.

For $n = 1$ the only map is the identity map on $X$ both subsets $\emptyset, X \subseteq X$ are stable, so $\deg \operatorname{id}_X = 2$. Now $\delta(2) \leq \delta(1) + 1 = 1$. For $d > 2$, $\delta(d)$ is always the sum of two positive numbers, so larger than $1$. Therefore, $2$ is the only number $> 1$ with stable subset depth at most $1$.

For $n > 1$ proceed by induction. Assume $\delta(d) \leq n$ for some $d  > 1$. Since $d > 1$, we have $\delta(d) = \delta(d-1) + 1$ or $\delta(d) = \delta(a) + \delta(b)$, where $d = ab$ and both $a$ and $b$ are larger than $1$. In the first case, $\delta(d-1) \leq n-1$, and $d-1 \in D_{\delta(d-1)}$. Choose $f \colon X \to X$ such that $\#X = \delta(d-1)$ and $\deg f = d-1$. Choose an element $* \notin X$. On $X_* = X \cup \{*\}$ define the map $f_*$ via $*\mapsto *$, $x \mapsto *$ if $x$ is a fixed point of $f$, and $x \mapsto f(x)$ if $x \in X$ is not a fixed point. The $f_*$-stable subsets are exactly $\emptyset$ and $S \cup \{*\}$, where $S$ is a stable subset of $X$. This means $\deg f_* = d$, so $d \in D_{\delta(d-1)+1} \subseteq D_n$.

In the second case, there are $f \colon X \to X$ and $g \colon Y \to Y$ such that $\deg f = a$, $\deg g = b$, $\#X = \delta(a)$, and $\#Y = \delta(b)$. Define $Z = X \sqcup Y$ (disjoint union) and $h \colon Z \to Z$, $x \mapsto f(x)$ for $x \in X$, $y \mapsto g(y)$ for $y \in Y$. The $h$-stable subsets in $Z$ are exactly the sets of the form $A \sqcup B$ such that $A \subseteq X$ and $B \subseteq Y$ are stable. This implies $\deg h = ab = d$, so $d \in D_{\delta(a) + \delta(b)} = D_{\delta(d)} \subseteq D_n$.

Now for the reverse inclusion! Let $d \in D_n$. Let $m \leq n$ be the minimal number such that $d \in D_m$. Choose $f \colon X \to X$ such that $\deg f = d$ and $\#X = m$. By the lemma, all cycles are given by fixed points. Let $x \in X$ be a fixed point (exists, since there always exists a cycle). If $x$ is the only fixed point, endow the set $X \setminus \{x\}$ with the following map $\tilde f$: $y \mapsto f(y)$ if $f(y) \neq x$. Otherwise, $y \mapsto y$. The $\tilde f$-stable subsets here are exactly the sets of the form $S \setminus \{x\}$, where $S \subseteq X$ is $f$-stable. Since all $f$-stable sets are either empty or contain $x$, we know that $\tilde f$ has one stable subset less than $f$. Thus, $\deg \tilde f = d - 1$, so $d - 1 \in D_{m-1}$. By induction, $\delta(d-1) \leq m-1 \leq n-1$, yielding $\delta(d) \leq \delta(d-1) + 1 \leq n$.

If, on the other hand, there are other fixed points than $x$, define $A = \{y \in X : \exists k \in \mathbb{N}_0 : f^k(y) = x\}$ and let $B$ be its complement. Both are non-empty since $x \in A$ and all other fixed points are in $B$. Moreover, both $A$ and $B$ are $f$-stable. Let $a$ and $b$ denote the degree of $f$ when restricted to $A$ and $B$, respectively. Note that $a,b > 1$ since $A$ and $B$ are non-empty. Similarly to two paragraphs ago, $d = \deg f = ab$. By induction, $a \in D_{\#A}$ and $b \in D_{\#B}$ implies $\delta(a) \leq \#A$ and $\delta(b) \leq \#B$. We finally get $\delta(d) \leq \delta(a) + \delta(b) \leq \#A + \#B = m \leq n$. $\square$

<s>Therefore, finding the possible degrees of functions on $n$ elements boils down to computing stable subset depths. I tried to find the function $\delta$ in OEIS, but there doesn't seem to exist a corresponding entry. This makes me believe that there probably doesn't exist a way to calculate $\delta(d)$ that is much easier than the recursive definition. My guess is that this description of $D_n$ and $\delta(d)$ is as good as it may get. I would be happy to be proven wrong, though.</s>

UPDATE 2: The sequence $\delta$ is described by OEIS. It is [A117498](https://oeis.org/A117498). I had a miscalculation in my list, so I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: I believe that $2^n-1$ is not possible in the general case.

Comment: Technically this does answer my question "can all values between $2$ and $2^n$ be taken?". But please look at my edited question and see if you can provide some insight.

Comment: I will. Just wanted to get this first result to you. You'll get an update if I manage to find out more.

Comment: @aqualubix Since the stable subset depth function is not on OEIS, I want to suggest that it be added there. With your consent I will take care of that.

Comment: @Tzimmo, sure go ahead. But can you link it here once done? I will go through your updated answer meanwhile.

Comment: Sure, I will add the link to the answer. It might take a little time until the database entry is published, though.

Comment: @Tzimmo, cool :)